# PHP changing string with "<" char

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting crazy with this... I just put something simple like this:

```
$pass = "axX/dss(z\<zbE";
die($pass);
```

and PHP return this:

```
axX/dss(z\
```

And every string that I put the "<" char occurs the same, the string is "shorted" by the "<" character.

Help please...

Thanks.

Oh, I'm using CodeIgniter.

---

OK

This is getting freak...

Now my code is like this:

```
$pass = "dsJ<32.\wwe^";
echo $pass;
echo '<br>';
$pass = "cz\vU(rV<zbE";
echo $pass;
```

And my return is:

```
dsJ<32.\wwe^
czU(rV
```

The first string uses de "<" char, and it's OK... but the second...

Comment: `view source` in your web browser, and then tell us if it's still not showing the `zbE`

Comment: `<` should be escaped in html (and xml as well) as `&lt;`

Comment: use `$pass = "axX/dss(z\&lt;zbE";` or `$pass = htmlentities("axX/dss(z\<zbE");`. html'n'tities FTW :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string isn't being changed at all. See here: http://3v4l.org/b3RaQ

What's happening is your *browser* is hiding the `<` character, it looks like HTML.

If you want to display the string in the browser properly, wrap it with `htmlentites()` or `<pre>` tags when troubleshooting.

UPDATE: I also copy/pasted your new code, which you can see here: http://3v4l.org/Uq9HY. It's still working. Maybe you can setup a test case at http://3v4l.org/ that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'd tried all of this...
I'm trying to connect to a database, and it's returning the error, because PHP is interpretting th $pass inconpleted.

In my browser source code just 'axX/dss(z\' is being showing... even printing "<pre>$pass</pre>" it isn't correct.

Comment: @KaduAzevedo Did you click the example link I gave you? It's clearly showing the correct output.

Comment: @Ejay I just meant if you're looking to spit it out in the browser and make sure you're seeing the exact value. Obviously you wouldn't use <pre> tags in your production code, just troubleshooting

Comment: If I try with the ">" char, it works, like with others chars (^~´`)... only the "<" char is breaking it up.

Comment: @KaduAzevedo The link I gave you, which tests the actual two lines of code you provided, is working. Something else is your problem, and we'd need more of your code to see what it is. Create a test php page with nothing but your two lines of code (and view source) and you'll see that's not your issue.

Comment: I saw your link, and I can see that it works... but in my code, I'm still getting this. Trying another test (you can see above) it gets more strange.

Comment: See my new link. Your new code still works. Give us a reproducible case at 3v4l.org

Answer (score 0):

Escape it with `&lt;`. `<` is a common symbol in html (and in php, by extension)